# How to post json in lua using cURL

Tags: json, curl, post, lua

I'm trying to post json in Lua using cURL. I can't find any example online.

Something like this:

```
    c = curl.easy{
  url      = "http://posttestserver.com/post.php",
  -- url      = "http://httpbin.org/post",
  post     = true,
  httppost = curl.form{

      data = "{}",
      type = "application/json",

  },
}
t = {}
 c:perform{
        writefunction = function(s)
            t[#t+1] = s
        end
    }

c:close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
local cURL = require "cURL"

c = cURL.easy{
  url        = "http://posttestserver.com/post.php",
  post       = true,
  httpheader = {
    "Content-Type: application/json";
  };
  postfields = "{}";
}

c:perform()
```

Comment: I think I need add this to examples :)

Comment: Good idea, it might help somebody to save couple hours. ;) Anyway, thank you a lot! You are awesome!

Comment: Maybe you can show how I can return 200 for ok and error code if something went wrong? Still can't figure it out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use `c:getinfo_response_code()` after perform. You can find all avaliable option in [official documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE.html)